# Jquery serialize : trying to pass a form status to an ASP.NET MVC controller without submitting the form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Working on an ASP.NET MVC application.
A form has several buttons submitting the form.
One of the buttons needs to send to the controller the form's controls status without submitting the form.
I plan to use Ajax and $('#FormID').serialize();

I wrote it this way:

```
  function rechercher() {
        var formStatus = $('#FormID').serialize();

        var url = '@Url.Action("Search", "ImproItemForm"); //?'+ formStatus;
        // alert('formStatus: ' + formStatus); //works fine
         alert('url: ' + url);

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:/* { improItem: formStatus },*/  formStatus ,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            success: function (result) {
                   alert("success" + result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                   alert("failure" + result);
            }
        });
    }
```

My controller action is as below:

```
public ActionResult Search(FormCollection improItem)
{
}
```

If I call ajax this way, it never reaches the controller (and thus triggers the error function.

If I comment this line:

```
data: formStatus ,
```

Then it does invoke the controller method but the FormCollection improItem argument has no values of course.
So I suppose that I am not passing the data correctly to Ajax but I do not manage to get this sorted.

thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you specify the correct content type. Right now you seem to have specified `application/json; charset=utf-8` but obviously you aren't sending any JSON but rather `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is how the `.serialize()` method will format the form values. So just get rid of this line:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Usually when you are unsure about what you are sending or receiving instead of trying to explicitly specify it like you did, you'd better don't specify anything and leave jQuery figure it out. The same stands true of course for the `dataType: 'json',` property. If your controller action doesn't return JSON, this will cause an error. If on the other hand you don't specify the expected return type, then jQuery will simply use the `Content-Type` response header that the server returned and it will figure it out.

So bottom line: leave it to the framework figure it out unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Ah, and before I forget, please replace this:

```
public ActionResult Search(FormCollection improItem)
```

with:

```
public ActionResult Search(MyViewModel improItem)
```

Comment: Brillant!! Thanks a ton Darin :)